# MySql SELECT statement with where LIKE not returning results

Tags: mysql, where-clause

MySql statement does not return any results when I include `WHERE LIKE`.

**Statement:**

```
SELECT aes_decrypt(SchoolName, 'MyString') as SchoolName from SchoolList Where aes_decrypt(SchoolName, 'MyString') LIKE '% Part of School Name Here%'
```

If I remove the `LIKE` it works

```
SELECT aes_decrypt(SchoolName, 'MyString') as SchoolName from SchoolList Where aes_decrypt(SchoolName, 'MyString') = 'School Name Here'
```

Comment: Where is the PHP code?

Comment: The php is not relevant, this happens when I test in MySql

Comment: "The php is not relevant, this happens when I test in MySql" then don't tag it with PHP

Comment: My apologies ..

Comment: Did you check the manual from MySQL about using AES functions? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt they advice using a UNHEX in combination with SHA2 string as key input.. There is also a Note and Caution notice about using AES functions of you scroll up more..

Comment: Thanks. My other statements works perfect, It is only when I include the LIKE

Comment: The first query does use a `=` not `LIKE` operator by the way.. `%` wildchars only work in combination with `LIKE` operator.

Comment: Edited. But still does not work

Comment: But i wonder why you would use AES to encrypt a public known school name by the way.

Comment: There is logical reasoning behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the result of `aes_decrypt` to char in order to use `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT aes_decrypt(SchoolName, 'MyString') as SchoolName 
from SchoolList 
Where cast(aes_decrypt(SchoolName, 'MyString') as CHAR) LIKE '% Part of School Name Here%'
```

See this example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m1ynqMzVqSs5yTeTmrqUbP/1